# Improve `Update` sub query performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query like this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET status = 'ANSWERED' WHERE table1.number IN (select table2.number from table2)
```

It should update `status` to ANSWERED if `table1.number` are already exist in `table2.number`

It is taking forever and still hanging..

In the `table1` table, 300,000 rows.

In the `table2` table, 24,000 rows.

`table1.number` and `table2.number` are the unique numbers.

how to improve the performance?

Comment: Use joins instead of IN to make use of indexes, disable keys before query/enable keys after query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create index on table1.number and table2.number fields and use the following query.

```
UPDATE table1 
       INNER JOIN table2 
               ON table1.number = table2.number 
SET    table1.status = 'ANSWERED'
```